# Avg invoice amount by total invoice

Tags: excel

i have the below power piviot table (data model)

```
customer #  salesman    invoice#    item #  qty price   amount
  a1           jack        1          11     2  12.00   24.00
  a1           jack        1          12     3  10.00   30.00
  b1           john        2          11     1  12.00   12.00
  b1           john        2          12     3  5.00    15.00
  b1           john        2          13     5  6.00    30.00
```

i would like to get a measure that would give me average invoice amount

what it would have to do is total up the amount column for each invoice and then give me an average of that total

how can i accomplish that? any help is appreciated

thanks

Comment: AVERAGEIFS()???

Comment: Pivot Table????

Answer (score 0):

For your invoices totals, use the SUMIFS formula:

```
=SUMIFS(G2:G6,C2:C6,1)
```

Where column G are your line totals and column C are your invoice numbers.  Also, the last "1" in the formula really should be referenced to a cell that contains the invoice number you are trying to output the total for, otherwise you'll have to manually change the formula for each different invoice

Similarly, use the AVERAGEIFS formula to get your invoice averages:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(G2:G6,C2:C6,1)
```